# IOFileNotFoundException mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, unit-testing, silverlight, windows-phone, mscorlib

I try to run unit tests for Windows Phone Silverlight. When an exception is thrown, I constantly receive the next exception instead of the real exception (for instance, ParseException). I think it has something to do with the culture it is asking.

Message:

> Could not load file or assembly 'mscorlib.debug.resources,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=nl-NL, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Stacktrace:

> at System.Environment.GetResourceFromDefaultUsedFallback(String key,
>   CultureInfo culture, Boolean& usedFallback) at
>   System.Environment.GetResourceString(String key, Object[] values) at
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException.ToString()

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to run the unit tests on a device whose language is set to `nl-NL`?

I solved my similar-sounding problem by switching the device language to `en-US`.